# Async Await without using async Await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am trying to convert my code from using Async/Await methods to basic .then() promises. The reason is that Async/Await does not work on IE. 
I am new to promises and came in late with finally getting a hang of using Async/Await but now need to convert back in time a little to make my code work in IE.

Working code using Async/Await [here](https://codepen.io/theller5567/pen/MqYyzr) on Codepen.io

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Javascript trying not to use Async/Await:**

```
const getPromise = () => {  
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $.getJSON( countriesUrl, function( data ) {
      }).done(function(data){
        resolve(data);
      }).fail(function(error){
        var reason = new Error('mom is not happy today');
        reject(reason);
     });
    }, 500);
  });
};


var bcp = {
init: function(){
  bcp.topbar = parseInt($('.topbar').css('height'), 10);
  bcp.bottombar = parseInt($('.bottom-bar').css('height'), 10);
  if(!bcp.countriesLoaded){
    console.log('testing');
      bcp.addCountries().then((countries) => {
        console.log('hello');
      bcp.popup = $($.fancybox.getInstance().current.src)[0];
      bcp.distributorArrays(countries);
    });
  }else {
    bcp.addEventListeners();
  }
},
toggleCountrySection: function(){
  $('#locationModal').find('.loading').toggleClass('show');
  $('.content').toggle();
},
getCountries: function() {
  console.log('get Countries');
  bcp.toggleCountrySection();
},
addCountries: function() {
  (() => {
      getPromise()
      .then(result => {
        console.log('result', result);
        var data = result;
        return data;
      }).then(function(data){
        var countries = data;
          bcp.toggleCountrySection();
          bcp.countriesLoaded = true;
          console.log('test', countries);
          return countries;
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
      });
  })();
};
```

I never receive the console.log('hello'). So my function bcp.addCountries().then((countries) => {}) is not retruning anytihng or i feel like i am not using the .then() properly.

**Here is my working code using Async/Await:**

```
init: function(){
  bcp.topbar = parseInt($('.topbar').css('height'), 10);
  bcp.bottombar = parseInt($('.bottom-bar').css('height'), 10);
  if(!bcp.countriesLoaded){
      bcp.addCountries().then((countries) => {
      bcp.popup = $($.fancybox.getInstance().current.src)[0];
      bcp.distributorArrays(countries);
    });
  }else {
    bcp.addEventListeners();
  }
},
toggleCountrySection: function(){
  $('#locationModal').find('.loading').toggleClass('show');
  $('.content').toggle();
},
getCountries: function() {
  console.log('get Countries');
  bcp.toggleCountrySection();
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $.ajax({
        url: countriesUrl,
        success: function(data) {
          var results = JSON.parse(data);
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
    }, 1500);
  });
},
addCountries: async function() {
  var countries = await bcp.getCountries();
  bcp.toggleCountrySection();
  bcp.countriesLoaded = true;
  return countries;
},
```

Comment: May be using a transpiler like Babel will be easier for you.

Comment: https://medium.com/@zwacky/add-es7-async-await-support-into-your-non-bleeding-edge-build-process-ad0dded0d002

Comment: I do not want to use a build process or transpiler.

Comment: But ES6 promises do not work in Internet Explorer either?

Comment: I am using bluebird.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the working version (*from your comment `Here is my working code using Async/Await:`*) and change `addCountries` to this.

Answer used:

```
return bcp.getCountries().then((countries) => {
    console.log('test', countries);
    bcp.toggleCountrySection();
    bcp.countriesLoaded = true;
    return countries;
});
```

Comment: When I plugged your code in the bcp.addCountries is not returning countries and so when i console.log(countries) it comes up as undefined. I posted the codepen of the working code where you would be able to test it out if that helps.

Comment: Hey @Igor, I ended up using your code but return countries from within the function and it worked. Thanks